# Intellij IDEA different color schemes for files

Tags: java, typescript, intellij-idea

How can i choose different color schemes for different file types (for example Java and TypeScript) in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> -> intelliJ Preferences -> Editor 
> -> Color & Fonts -> Select the category and update the colors accordingly.
> ```

Here is the [help documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) around 2017.1 version of intelliJIDEA.

Screenshot sample as below - 
[image]

Comment: If i have 2 themes, witch match for my need, I can copy all settings for certain type of files from 1 theme to another?

Comment: Yes. You can duplicate the configurations for different themes(scheme).

Comment: @MolecularMan - If you mean get the same configuration in two different existing schemes. You would have to update them individually. Duplicate works for creating a new scheme altogether. But does not copy the custom changes you've made to the Editor.

Comment: I mean: I have theme A which is good for Java code and theme B - for TypeScript. I want to apply those A for Java and B for TypeScript at the same time or copy settings for Java from A to B (or vice versa)

Comment: The color and font can be modified within a Theme(e.g Darcula) for both Java and Typescript. Referencing the screenshot as there you can see Go, JSON, HTML etc. If you need to maintain two different themes for these two languages, then it makes sense update both the themes with specific font and color for each language.

Comment: Is there any way to make it (update one theme from another) automaticaly or I have to do this manually?

Comment: As already said **If you mean to get the same configuration in two different existing schemes. You would have to update them individually.**

Answer (score 0):

It should work over File - Settings - Editor Color & Fonts -> type, but it does not work, possible a bug in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.4 for Linux